# How do I force refresh an ObjectDataSource?

Tags: asp.net

In my ASP.NET web forms I find that the ObjectDataSource won't update/refresh **when the SelectParameter values do not change**.

How do I force refresh an ObjectDataSource regardless of whether or not the parameter values change?

Example code:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsUserSearchResults" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetData" EnablePaging="false" 
    TypeName="MySolution.ObjectDataSources.Users">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="name" ControlID="txtName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="statusId" ControlID="ddlStatus" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters> 
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to **disable the object data source view state** by setting the EnableViewState property to false, like so:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="odsUserSearchResults" EnableViewState="false" runat="server" 
    SelectMethod="GetData" EnablePaging="false" 
    TypeName="MySolution.ObjectDataSources.Users">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="name" ControlID="txtName" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter Name="statusId" ControlID="ddlStatus" PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
    </SelectParameters> 
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```